# Save an image from url to file

Tags: go

Very new to Go (first simple project I'm working on).

Question: How do I get an image from URL and then save it to my computer?

Here's what I have so far:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"net/http"
"image"
"io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
        url := "http://i.imgur.com/m1UIjW1.jpg"
        // don't worry about errors
    response, _ := http.Get(url);

    defer response.Body.Close()
    m, _, err := image.Decode(response.Body)

    error := ioutil.WriteFile("/images/asdf.jpg", m, 0644)
}
```

However, when I run this code, I get `cannot use m (type image.Image) as type []byte in function argument`

I'm assuming I have to convert image.Image (variable `m`) into an undefined amount of bytes?  Is that the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is no need to decode the file. Simply copy the response body to a file you've opened. Here's the deal in the modified example:

1. `response.Body` is a stream of data, and implements the `Reader` interface - meaning you can sequentially call `Read` on it, as if it was an open file.
2. The file I'm opening here implements the `Writer` interface. This is the opposite - it's  a stream you can call `Write` on.
3. `io.Copy` "patches" a reader and a writer, consumes the reader stream and writes its contents to a Writer.

This is one of my favorite things about go - implicit interfaces. You don't have to declare you're implementing an interface, you just have to implement it to be used in some context. This allows mixing and matching of code that doesn't need to know about other code it's interacting with.

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    url := "http://i.imgur.com/m1UIjW1.jpg"
    // don't worry about errors
    response, e := http.Get(url)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    //open a file for writing
    file, err := os.Create("/tmp/asdf.jpg")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Use io.Copy to just dump the response body to the file. This supports huge files
    _, err = io.Copy(file, response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Success!")
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading the code right, it's 1) getting the image via response.Body, 2) creating an empty file (asdf.jpg), 3) taking asdf.jpg and making the data response.Body?  Code does work so I'll accept when time limit is up

Comment: I'll add an explanation in the answer.

Comment: The error for `http.Get(url)` is ignored in this example. If it fails, the resulting image will be empty. It should report the error and exit.

Comment: @jimt of course.  I explicitly was skipping over the errors in my post (which is probably why Not_a_Golfer skipped it too). I figured they were obvious to do.  Hopefully I didn't cause anyone any confusion.

Comment: If you do skip error handling, never do it on the internet where children can see it. For better or worse, people come here to learn. Always demonstrate your best code when offering examples. This will be someone else's production code.

Comment: @Dustin Two years after the fact, I am helping a friend learn to program.  I was reviewing his php code and he had 0 error handling.  He said he got everything working by doing tutorials online.  You are absolutely correct Dustin... always show error handling.

Answer (score 7):

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    img, _ := os.Create("image.jpg")
    defer img.Close()

    resp, _ := http.Get("http://i.imgur.com/Dz2r9lk.jpg")
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    b, _ := io.Copy(img, resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("File size: ", b)
}
```

Comment: It returns: `File size:  0` though the file correctly downloaded!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var (
    fileName    string
    fullUrlFile string
)

func main() {
    fullUrlFile = "https://i.imgur.com/m1UIjW1.jpg"
    r, e := http.Get(fullUrlFile)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    buildFileName()
    // Create distination
    f, e := os.Create(fileName) // "m1UIjW1.jpg"
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // Fill distination with content
    n, e := f.ReadFrom(r.Body)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    fmt.Println("File size: ", n)
}

func buildFileName() {
    fileUrl, e := url.Parse(fullUrlFile)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    path := fileUrl.Path
    segments := strings.Split(path, "/")

    fileName = segments[len(segments)-1]
    println(fileName)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `ReadFrom` method:

```
package main

import (
   "net/http"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   r, e := http.Get("https://i.imgur.com/m1UIjW1.jpg")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   f, e := os.Create("m1UIjW1.jpg")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   f.ReadFrom(r.Body)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/os#File.ReadFrom

Comment: Nice, clean way, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `response.Body`?  You should just convert that into a `[]byte` if it is not and write that to disk.  There is no reason to use the `image` class unless you have some reason to treat the data as an image.  Just treat the data as a series of bytes and write it to the disk.