# Golang GAE Save Image Url to Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am looking to save an image in Go, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417283/save-an-image-from-url-to-file-go):

```
url := "http://i.imgur.com/m1UIjW1.jpg"

response, e := http.Get(url)
if e != nil {
    log.Fatal(e)
}

defer response.Body.Close()

file, err := os.Create("/tmp/asdf.jpg")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

_, err = io.Copy(file, response.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

file.Close()
```

However - I am using [Blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/reference) on GAE and all of the examples I find seem to be based on some multi-part form upload based on a [users browser](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/)...

How do I download an image on GAE/Blobstore with a simple GET request:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    urlImage := "http://i.imgur.com/m1UIjW1.jpg"
    //when a user calls this root handle, download urlImage to Blobstore
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, from context, that you mean "upload an image to blobstore" where you say "download an image on blobstore".

Once upon a time you would have created a `blobstore` `Writer` with https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/reference#Create , then written on it, and closed it. But as the docs mention this is now deprecated; nowadays, you use instead the package `cloud/storage` as in the example at `https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/storage#example-NewWriter`:

```
wc := storage.NewWriter(ctx, "bucketname", "filename1")
wc.ContentType = "image/jpg"
wc.ACL = []storage.ACLRule{{storage.AllUsers, storage.RoleReader}}
if _, err := wc.Write(response.Body); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

etc, etc -- compared to the example, I've only changed the content type and exactly what bytes you write.

Essentially, blobstore has been replaced by cloud storage, and you should use the latter.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and correction on context, I should have written upload and image!