# Golang Save File from URL to GCS Bucket in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to [get a image file from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417283/save-an-image-from-url-to-file) and save it to GCS storage using the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample#writing_a_file_to_cloud_storage).

I can't figure out how to create the file from `response.Body` to GSC given my AppEngine environment... I can't create using os.Create and reference a file path in this environment, right?

- Looking for tips on passing the `response.Body` to the `wc.Write()` method while deployed in AppEngine.

Code to get file:

```
func main() {
    url := "http://i.imgur.com/m1UIjW1.jpg"
    // don't worry about errors
    response, e := http.Get(url)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()

    //open a file for writing
    file, err := os.Create("/tmp/asdf.jpg")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Use io.Copy to just dump the response body to the file. This supports huge files
    _, err = io.Copy(file, response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    file.Close()
    fmt.Println("Success!")
}
```

Save a local file to GCS

```
func (d *demo) createFile(fileName string) {
        fmt.Fprintf(d.w, "Creating file /%v/%v\n", d.bucketName, fileName)

        wc := d.bucket.Object(fileName).NewWriter(d.ctx)
        wc.ContentType = "text/plain"
        wc.Metadata = map[string]string{
                "x-goog-meta-foo": "foo",
                "x-goog-meta-bar": "bar",
        }
        d.cleanUp = append(d.cleanUp, fileName)

        if _, err := wc.Write([]byte("abcde\n")); err != nil {
                d.errorf("createFile: unable to write data to bucket %q, file %q: %v", d.bucketName, fileName, err)
                return
        }
        if _, err := wc.Write([]byte(strings.Repeat("f", 1024*4) + "\n")); err != nil {
                d.errorf("createFile: unable to write data to bucket %q, file %q: %v", d.bucketName, fileName, err)
                return
        }
        if err := wc.Close(); err != nil {
                d.errorf("createFile: unable to close bucket %q, file %q: %v", d.bucketName, fileName, err)
                return
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a [Writer](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewWriter) and a [bytes.Buffer](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer):

```
var buff bytes.Buffer
writer := NewWriter(buff)
n, err := io.Copy(writer, response.Body)
```