# Save an image from url to blob

Tags: go

I can download an image from url to file as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70014573/2441637):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var (
    fileName    string
    fullUrlFile string
)

func main() {
    fullUrlFile = "https://i.imgur.com/m1UIjW1.jpg"
    r, e := http.Get(fullUrlFile)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    buildFileName()
    // Create distination
    f, e := os.Create(fileName) // "m1UIjW1.jpg"
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // Fill distination with content
    n, e := f.ReadFrom(r.Body)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    fmt.Println("File size: ", n)
}

func buildFileName() {
    fileUrl, e := url.Parse(fullUrlFile)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    path := fileUrl.Path
    segments := strings.Split(path, "/")

    fileName = segments[len(segments)-1]
    println(fileName)
}
```

But i my application, I want to save the image as blob directly from uel to indexedDB, in JavaScript this can be done as:

```
// Get the blob
// Create XHR
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    blob;

xhr.open("GET", "elephant.png", true);
// Set the responseType to blob
xhr.responseType = "blob";

xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log("Image retrieved");
        
        // File as response
        blob = xhr.response;

        // Put the received blob into IndexedDB
        transaction.objectStore("elephants").put(blob, "image");
    }
}, false);
// Send XHR
xhr.send();
```

My understanding the the `blob` is nothing but a `[]byte`, so I tried converting the `r.Body` read in the image downloading code to `[]byte` as:

```golang
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(r.Body)
    blob := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())

    dest, e := os.Create("test.jpg")
    n2, e := dest.ReadFrom(blob)
    fmt.Printf("The number of bytes are: %d\n", n2)
```

But it did not work!

The question is: How can I convert `[]bytes` read from an `io.Reader` to another `io.Reader` that I can save in another destination.

Comment: Show the code that requires two io.Readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, it was very simple, either using:

```golang
    var dest []byte
    blob := bytes.NewBuffer(dest)
    io.Copy(blob, r.Body)
```

or using:

```golang
    var dest []byte
    blob := bytes.NewBuffer(dest)
    b, e := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    src := bytes.NewReader(b)
    io.Copy(blob, src)
```

In both cases, once `r.Body` or any `io.Writer` created based on it, is valid for one time usage, after that it is consumed in full.

my code now became:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var (
    fileName    string
    fullUrlFile string
)

func main() {
    fullUrlFile = "https://i.imgur.com/m1UIjW1.jpg"
    r, e := http.Get(fullUrlFile)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    buildFileName()
    // Create blob
    var dest []byte
    blob := bytes.NewBuffer(dest)
    io.Copy(blob, r.Body)

    add_to_database(blob)
}
func buildFileName() {
    fileUrl, e := url.Parse(fullUrlFile)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    path := fileUrl.Path
    segments := strings.Split(path, "/")

    fileName = segments[len(segments)-1]
    println(fileName)
}

func add_to_database(blob *bytes.Buffer){}
```